# How to add Service reference in The development of window phone 7 app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, window

How to add Service reference in The development of window phone 7 app?
I want all steps or Demo of that steps in visual studio 2010 for window phone.

Answer (score 0):

1. RightClick on "References" in the project.
2. Select "Add Service reference".
3. Enter the URL of the web service.
4. Click Go.
5. Select the service you require.
6. Click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Above steps will help you to add the service reference in the project. As mentioned in the 3rd and 4th steps "Enter the URL of the Web service" and "clicking on Go button", we can also browse the available services by clicking on the Discover button.